# Exercise 3.2.2.d in Grimmett & Stirzaker's 'Probability and Random Processes'

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

The questions asks: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables taking values in the positive integers and having the same mass function $f(x)=2^{-x}$ for $x=1,2,...$ find:

$P(X\geq kY)$ for a given positive integer $k$

$$\begin{align*}
P(X\geq kY) &= \sum_{y=1}^\infty (X\geq kY, Y=y) \\\\
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty (X\geq kY)P(Y=y) \;\;\;\; \text{due to independence}  \\\\
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{x+ky}} \frac{1}{2^y} \\\\
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{x+ky+1}}
\end{align*}$$

The answer is

$$\frac{2}{2^{k+1}-1}$$

generally for a single geometric series the sum is:

$$\frac{1}{1-r}$$

$$\frac{1}{1-2^{k+1}}$$

$$\frac{2^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}-1}$$

Which has the correct denominator, can someone please explain how to the answer shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful, you have an algebraic error in your last equality. You should get:
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{x+{\color{red}{(k+1)y}}}} &= \sum_{y=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{(k+1)y}}  \underbrace{\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{x}}}_{=2} \\
&= 2\sum_{y=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2^{k+1})^y} \\
&= 2\cdot \frac{2^{-(k+1)}}{1 - 2^{-(k+1)}} \\
&= \frac{2}{2^{k+1}-1}
\end{align*}$$
where in the last step I multiplied the numerator and denominator by $2^{k+1}$.

Comment: Hi Jose, In the second last line the denominator makes sense assuming it comes from the standard expression for a geometric series sum. but why is there 2^{-k+1} in the numerator can you break that part down please?

Comment: @Bazman an infinite geometric sum equals $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio